# nginx server different of apache server error

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, nginx, server

```
 $('#uploadfm').ajaxSubmit({
                    type:'post',
                    dataType:'text', 
                    url:'/api/user/import?Authorization='+mytoken,
                    success:function(res){},
                    error:function(err){}
});
```

the front is ajax request , java backend content-type is text/plain.
when I to test IE8/9 browser that if i use apache server proxy to nginx this request response success
but if i use nginx proxy  this request response current page html string .
I found listen to network this url request response normail but why ajax response error?

please help me thanks.

Comment: I think this is an half baked question, first I am not sure what are you trying to ask, second when you are getting an error, what is the error message? You also said you are using proxy server apache and nginx, is that on development environment or production? Which OS you are using?

Comment: May be I didn't describe clearly, the first network request there is no error, again under the apache agent is no problem, but if with nginx proxy, with browser monitoring view url request is no problem, but the problem appears in my success with ajax request return not those normal returns the content of the url, but returned to the current page content, I can speak clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now this question has resolve , because iframe option set error